# AWS API Gateway Method to Serve static content from S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I want to serve my lambda microservices through API Gateway which seems not to be a big problem.

Every of my microservices has a JSON-Schema specification of the resource provided. Since it is a static file, I would like to serve it from an S3 Bucket 
rather than also running a lambda function to serve it.

So while

```
GET,POST,PUT,DELETE http://api.domain.com/ressources
```

should be forwarded to a lambda function. I want

```
GET http://api.domain.com/ressources/schema
```

to serve my schema.json from S3.

My naive first approach was to setup the resource and methods for "/v1/contracts/schema - GET - Integration Request" and configure it to behave as an HTTP Proxy with endpoint url pointing straight to the contracts JSON-Schema. I get a 500 - Internal Server error.

```
                    Execution log for request test-request
Fri Nov 27 09:24:02 UTC 2015 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Fri Nov 27 09:24:02 UTC 2015 : API Key: test-invoke-api-key
Fri Nov 27 09:24:02 UTC 2015 : Method request path: {}
Fri Nov 27 09:24:02 UTC 2015 : Method request query string: {}
Fri Nov 27 09:24:02 UTC 2015 : Method request headers: {}
Fri Nov 27 09:24:02 UTC 2015 : Method request body before transformations: null
Fri Nov 27 09:24:02 UTC 2015 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid endpoint address
```

Am I on a complete wrong path or do I just miss some configurations ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a limitation when using TestInvoke with API Gateway proxying to Amazon S3 (and some other AWS services) within the same region. This will not be the case once deployed, but if you want to test from the console you will need to use a bucket in a different region.

We are aware of the issue, but I can't commit to when this issue would be resolved.

Comment: thx for the info. This issue will be the same no matter if i use the HTTP Proxy or AWS Service Option, right?

Comment: This is exceedingly annoying. Just spent a morning trying to track down an issue from one of Amazon's tutorials which only exists in the test environment.

Comment: @BobKinney, has this issue been fixed?

Comment: @JosephCarroll unfortunately not.

Comment: I'm still seeing the same problem that @QuantumTiger is seeing. It's unfortunate that Amazon's documentation seems to be a bit outdated.

Comment: @BobKinney I am acutally having this problem after deployment, in the TestInvoke it works perfectly

Comment: @MatanKadosh please either open a support case with details or post on our forums and we can follow up.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my setups I put a CloudFront distribution in front of both an API Gateway and an S3 bucket, which are both configured as origins.

I did mostly it in order to be able to make use of an SSL certificate issued by the AWS Certificate manager, which can only be set on stand-alone CloudFront distributions, and not on API Gateways.

Comment: sure it is possible with cloudfront, but I think you can't get the same level of detailed routing. Or am I wrong. You can just have different subdomains one point to S3 and another to API Gateway

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar error, but for a totally different reason: if the s3 bucket name contains a period (as in data.example.com or similar), the proxz request will bail out with a ssl certification issue!