# New API not connecting to server on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create my first API using API Gateway to talk to our server on an EC2 instance. I have nothing in the Method Request configuration screen and only 'HTTP Proxy' and the URL of my EC2 instance. No parameters, query strings, or headers set up. I can connect to the my EC2 instance from my machine and from the other instance that houses our UI just fine.

I'm getting the following error when running the Test in the UI.

```
Execution log for request test-request
Fri Sep 02 22:10:43 UTC 2016 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Fri Sep 02 22:10:43 UTC 2016 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /subjects
Fri Sep 02 22:10:43 UTC 2016 : Method request path: {}
Fri Sep 02 22:10:43 UTC 2016 : Method request query string: {}
Fri Sep 02 22:10:43 UTC 2016 : Method request headers: {}
Fri Sep 02 22:10:43 UTC 2016 : Method request body before transformations: null
Fri Sep 02 22:10:43 UTC 2016 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid endpoint address
Fri Sep 02 22:10:43 UTC 2016 : Method completed with status: 500
```

When I look in the logs for my server I see no errors or any indication that the API Gateway test is touching my server. I don't know why the endpoint address would be invalid since it works everywhere else.

Is it possible there's a Security Group or firewall of some kind that stops traffic from API Gateway to EC2? It's in my corporate VPC setup so I'm not familiar with all the networking bits that might be configured.

Comment: API Gateway is not able to connect to the EC2 instance in your VPC without a public IP address. Please confirm your EC2 instance has a public IP address is associated with.

Comment: If Ka Hou's suggestion doesn't work, please try deploying your API and testing it via curl. Behavior of your API can be slightly different between Test Invoke and an actual deployed API. You will also get a request ID this way (x-amzn-RequestId HTTP response header).

Comment: @LorenzodeLara ["slightly" different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33974245/1695906) indeed.